# row index in pandas read_table

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading the following array into pandas dataframe:

```
1 0.140000 0.180000 0.200000
2 0.240000 0.320000 0.320000
3 0.340000 0.430000 0.460000

pd.read_table("test.txt", sep = ' ', header = None, index_col= 0)
```

This works, except I get an empty "zero" row:

```
      1     2     3
0                                                                 
1   0.14  0.18  0.20
2   0.24  0.32  0.32
3   0.34  0.43  0.46
```

How do I fix the row index?

Thank you.

Comment: Try setting index_col = None instead of 0.

Comment: Then the first column, which indices the rows becomes data, no?

Comment: oh yes, that may happen. I can't reproduce this issue on my side so difficult to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, '0' is the index name in this dataframe, to get rid of this name, you can use the following:

```
pd.read_table(textfile, sep = ' ', header = None, index_col = 0).rename_axis(None)
```

Output:

```
      1     2     3
1  0.14  0.18  0.20
2  0.24  0.32  0.32
3  0.34  0.43  0.46
```